# Are Dirac points the norm for 2D band structure?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, graphene, optical-lattices

I've been doing simulations of band structure for 2D optical lattices, and something I've noticed is that, for sufficiently shallow lattices, there are typically points on the edge of the first Brillouin zone where the lowest bands touch (or nearly touch).  These smell like Dirac points, though I don't know this rigorously.

My question is: Is there an analytical argument why Dirac points should be the norm for 2D lattices?  If so, what can be said analytically about the location of these points?

Comment: Just a sanity-check question: these aren't just the normal points where the parabolic free-space dispersion is split by the lattice, right? Do you know that they are actually points and not slightly rounded edges?

Comment: @Rococo No, they're not the points you refer to: As I deepen the lattice they slide around the edge of the Brillouin zone.